# Image used for wordpress posts on Facebook

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I've seen it several times on my facebook timeline where the image of a shared link is not in the post itself. Example:

https://www.facebook.com/BarakaBits/posts/1065758210116791 - Image has text on it.
[screenshot](http://note.io/1EWF0xp)

Here's the post itself: http://www.barakabits.com/2015/01/beauty-moroccos-diversity-captured-stunning-photo-series

Is this a hidden image? I'm using a wordpress blog, how can I do this? Do I need a special plugin?

Thank you in advance!
Wil

Comment: I have just shared and im unable to see that image...but it would be possible trough to change the shared image. I checkd the meta also and there nothing special.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the image that appears on facebook: http://note.io/1EWF0xp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what this site is doing, but you can suggest that Facebook use a specific image (not necessarily one found on the page) by using the `og:image` Open Graph tag.  For example, something like this would go in the `<head>` portion of your site:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.barakabits.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Moroccos-faces-featured-6.jpg">
```

As you can see from the site you referenced, you can have multiple `og:image` tags, and the user will be able to choose which one is displayed in the post.

Here's Facebook's guide to Open Graph tags: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices